# Flex - how to disable/enable a group of components (or change a property)

Tags: apache-flex, permissions, flash-builder, field

How can I enable or disable a group of components in flex (flash builder 4)?

For example, if I have a window with several fields, I want to disable them based on the users permissions.

I know I can add the enabled="true" or "enabled="false", and I can also use enabled="{writeAccessVar}"

However, I am looking for more ideas, as I might have more than one group of fields on the screen, or more complicated user permissions.

For example, I will currently have one field with write access, the other fields on the screen read only for a certain user level.

For a higher level user, all fields are writable.   Lower level, all are read-only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a variable `accessLevel` that is equal to the access level of the user:

```
[Bindable]
var accessLevel:int = 0; // 0: low level, 1: next level, 2: next level, an so on
```

And then, you can set the `enabled` property of each component according to `accessLevel`:

```
enabled="{accessLevel >= 0}"
```

---

To improve the readability of your code, you can declare constants for the different levels

```
public static const ACCESS_LEVEL_LOW:int = 0;
public static const ACCESS_LEVEL_NORMAL:int = 1;
public static const ACCESS_LEVEL_HIGH:int = 2;


// ...
enabled="{accessLevel >= ACCESS_LEVEL_LOW}"
// ...
enabled="{accessLevel >= ACCESS_LEVEL_NORMAL}"
// ...
enabled="{accessLevel >= ACCESS_LEVEL_HIGH}"
```

Comment: So far I decided on this with a slight change.   I put this in my component:  enabled="{app.chkAcc('NW')}"     chkAcc is a method and I am passing a group name of NW to it.    Then in the method I check if the users access level (or group membership) and return true/false based on if they are a member of NW.

Comment: One issue I have run in to - when my app first loads, I have a button that is disabled, since the user is not logged in.   After the user logs in, I expected the button to become enabled, but it is not.  It's not calling my method, so I assume I have to do some kind of refresh to tell that window to redraw all the components.  I tried myWindow.invalidateDisplayList(); myWindow.validateNow();  , but no difference??

Comment: You have to use a bindable variable as I did in my example. For example, change `enabled="{app.chkAcc('NW')}"` into `enabled="{app.chkAcc(accessLevel)}"` where `accessLevel` is a bindable variable. In fact that's just replacing the test I did `enabled="{accessLevel >= 0}"` by a test that calls a function: `enabled="{app.chkAcc(accessLevel)}"`.

Comment: But I am checking 'accessLevel' in my method app.chkAcc.   The 'NW' is a static (constant) that is what level is required for the component to be enabled.   So the method has a line that looks like:  if(grp=="NW" && accessLevel>=5) return true;    The problem is, flex is drawing the component and setting enabled only once at application load.  I need a way to tell it to redraw the components after the login window closes.

Comment: Redawing the components, calling `myWindow.invalidateDisplayList()` or `validateNow()` will not affect the property `enabled`. Try something like `enabled="{app.chkAcc('NW', app.accessLevel)}"` Or make Make `chkAcc` a static function and use `enabled="{Utils.chkAcc('NW', app.accessLevel)}"`.